# What does the asterisk mean when combined with class in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm a newbie in CSS. In one of the excercises I was doing to do some practice with selectors, I've stumbled into this kind of rule:

`* .someclass { someproperty: somevalue }`

and I've alrealdy spent some hours trying to sort this out.

I know that the askerisk in CSS selectors means *every element* in the page. And I know that this kind of selector

`something1 something2` means *something2* contained in *something1*

Does this kind selector `* .someclass` mean *every element of class someclass contained into another element of the page?* Because this seems to be the case in this example, where the text inside *span* is only selected (and shown) **only if** contained in a *div*

```css
#expand-toggle {
        display: none;
      }

      .expandable {
        visibility: hidden;
        background: gray;
        color: white;
      }

      #expand-btn {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 12px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        background-color: #ff8888;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 3px;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      #expand-toggle:checked ~ * .expandable {
        visibility: visible;
      }

      #expand-toggle:checked ~ #expand-btn {
        background-color: #88ff88;
      }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="expand-toggle" />

    <span class="expandable">This is not contained in another container. Thus this is not selected</span>

    <div>
      <span class="expandable">This is contained in another container. Thus this is selected and shown</span>
    </div>
    
    <label for="expand-toggle" id="expand-btn">
    Click to show the text
    </label>
```

Comment: Basically `* .someclass ` is useless since it will apply to every element with that class except the HTML element.

Comment: Oh and "the asterisk in CSS selectors means every element in the page" is not quite true... it means **any element in the page** which is not quite the same thing but for practical purposes it is.

Answer (score 0):

the tilde symbol before the asterisks denotes the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), so the two combined means any element after `#expand-toggle:checked` that contains an element with the class `.expandable`